# trying to find out which web part has been used on the page

Tags: sharepoint

I am very new to sharepoint. I am asked to create a web part similar to the one that was created by another developer. I tried to edit the already existing web part and below window popped up:

[image]

Looking at the already existing properties of the web part. I tried to insert script web part, content editor web part and page Viewer web part one after another on my page, but none of them showed me the button saying Source editor. I also tried inserting HTML form web part and that didnt showed me the source editor button either.
I just want to insert the same web part that is inserted by the previous developer, but could not find which part he inserted ti get those kind of properties.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append contents=1 to your page, it will redirect to web part page maintenance and it will list the webparts in the page.

[image]